# Decryption of hashed passwords

Tags: laravel, yii, passwords

I am working on a website's framework translation. I have translate it from Yii php framework to Laravel. I have got an existing database and I have to provide login access to existing users to the new website.  The problem is now I am using Laravel and Laravel does not recognizes the hashed values of the previous framework. i.e the values that are stored in the database hashed by some method in Yii framework. Is there any way to resolve this. I am using Auth::attempt() method in Laravel.

Comment: Yii appears to use the same bcrypt algorithm. Show us how you're using `Auth::attempt`.

Comment: Transfer of the data to a temporary column - change the Authentication process to also check that column, using the old encryption method, and slowly convert all the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't... plain and simple...

hashing isn't encryption. hashing is one way, you can prove this to yourself by taking an md5 or shasum of a large file, since the file's size is larger than the hashes output, by pigeonhole principle hashes can't be restored...

you could try to rainbow table them with password lists, don't, because this is compromising users security.

you will probably have to figure out a way to mash Yii's auth module into Laravel, or use some sort of middle man auth bit... or just make everyone change passwords.

Answer (score 1):

The Yii framework generates password hashes through the crypt function, and according to the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-passwords.html) it generates BCrypt hashes. You can check this easily by looking at the hashes, BCrypt hashes start with `$2y`.

So Laravel should actually be able to check password with your hashes, if you cannot find a method which is integrated in Laravel itself, you can surely use the [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) function to check the hashes.

Comment: The hashed values are in the format sha256:1000://///////////. I have used a simple code using password_verify() and its not matching the hashed value and the password.

Comment: @HamzaNasim - That seems to be a non standard way to hash passwords, a sha256 with key stretching. Could you provide an example of such a password/hash pair? Is there some custom code in your application which generates the hashes?